# Can't step into for loop

Tags: delphi, debugging, for-loop

I've been having a strange problem that I've never seen before. Now I have a for loop:

```
var
 a,counter: byte;
begin
  a:=0; 
   for counter := 1 to 10 do//I put a breakpoint at this line
   begin
     a:=a*5;
     a:=a+counter;
   end;
end;
```

If I put a breakpoint at the line above and try to step into the loop I can't do it. The debugger immediately steps over the loop and goes to the end.In the end I get the right result, but I can't follow the loop step by step. I mean this is just a simple example and not the real task. I just want to know when in what circumstances does this happen? I definitely remember tracking through all the steps of a loop. I work with Delphi 2010.

Comment: You forgot about Optimizing Compilers. Your code does nothing.

Comment: `In the end I get the right result, but I can't follow the loop step by step.` You mean to say you get a=3051755? If this code is optimized away as all seem to agree I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @Johan, in the posted code there's no "result", right or wrong; the code never executes. This is not the real code (it says so in the last paragraph of the question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both lines of code in the loop can be completely optimized away; you do nothing with `a` outside the loop, so both of the assignments are unnecessary. After the optimization, the compiler is leaving

```
for counter := 1 to 10 do 
  ;
```

Actually, if you didn't have a breakpoint  there, the loop would be removed as well, as it does nothing.

If you're having problems with your code, and the info above doesn't help (using the variable `a` after the loop runs), you need to post your real code. This made-up code is very clear to analyze; the problem in your actual code may be this simple, or much more complex to analyze.

Comment: You mean "loop does nothing" because everything the loop deals with are just the variables scoped only to the procedure itself, right?

Comment: No, I mean the loop does nothing because it does nothing. Read the code - `a` is assigned the value `5`, and then immediately assigned the value of `a` (`5`) + the current value of `counter`, and then the loop runs again and repeats that same process. So all the loop does is assign `a` the values, immediately discarding each value assigned. With nothing meaningful happening in the loop, there's no reason to execute the loop.

Comment: @KenWhite, I can understand that since a is not used after the loop, the loop is useless. But the calculations inside the loop are not meaningless if they would be used afterwards. 1,7,38,194..etc are the resulting a values for the loop iterations.

Comment: "if they would be used afterwards" -- but they aren't are they.  ;-)

Comment: @LURD, in the code posted, there is no use of `a` outside the loop, and therefore any values assigned to it *are* 100% meaningless, so there's no need to run the loop. Please read what I wrote - I said "in the code posted". I also suggested that Mikayil post **real** code instead. Actually,  in the code posted `a` couldn't be available anywhere else, because the `var`, `begin`, and `end` limit the scope to only the code shown in the question.

Answer (score 7):

See does turning off optimization makes difference - in project options -> Compiling -> Code generation.

Comment: I often turn off Optimization while debugging so that I can get the value of a variable that's already been optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: I don't think that would help in this case; the code posted is absolutely meaningless with or without optimization on, and there would be zero reasons to even compile it. It can't possibly be needed; it's a `NOP`.

Comment: The OP wrote that the code is just an example, not real one. My answer is to point out that usually this kind of problem is due to optimization; switch it off and you should be able to step even into that meaningless loop...

Comment: Did you read "in this case" in my comment? :) I've suggested in more than one comment (and in my answer) that Mikayil post real code instead of this made-up non-functional block. I also just made an observation; turning off optimization with **the posted code** will probably still not allow stepping through the block.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment to Ken's answer, Mikayil hinted that the code is inside a procedure.
This would also be a sound assumption looking at the code.

So if we set up a test like this :

```
Procedure Test;
var
  a,counter: byte;
begin
  a:=0;
  for counter := 1 to 10 do//I put a breakpoint at this line
  begin
    a:=a*5;
    a:=a+counter;
  end;
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

Set optimization on :  Result - as observed by Mikayil, no stepping into loop possible.

Set optimization off : Result - stepping into loop possible, just as ain suggested.

Now also take into consideration, Mikayil's question in Ken's answer :
whether the inability to step into the loop was because of the local scope of the `a`.

Ken answered no, but this is not the case :

```
var
  a : byte; // scope of a is outside of the procedure

Procedure Test;
var
  counter: byte;
begin
  a:=0;
  for counter := 1 to 10 do//I put a breakpoint at this line
  begin
    a:=a*5;
    a:=a+counter;
  end;
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

Now it does not matter whether optimization is on or off, stepping into the loop is possible anyway.

So, ain is absolute correct in his answer. (Tested in XE2)

Update :

For enabling stepping into the loop there are three possibilities :

1. Set optimization off.
2. Declare `a` outside your local scope.
3. Insert a dummy operation using `a` after the loop. Like : `if (a < counter) then;`

Neither of these steps are uncommon debug procedures, which I find this question is all about.

Comment: I read Ken's comment as 'not because of scope, but because "a" is not used'. It's not because of scope because if you use 'a' after the loop, the assignments won't be optimized away even though 'a' is local. The compiler does not optimize your test case, because it doesn't bother to search for if 'a' is used anywhere else or not.

Comment: So did I and I'm not in disagreement in that matter. But the follow up question was whether the local scope of `a` made the loop not possible to step into. And in a comment to ain's answer Ken suggests that optimization on/off has nothing to do with the inability to step into the loop. This is not correct.

Comment: @MC9000, Delphi has nothing to do with VS. The compiler is able to optimize away loops that does not persist change of state. A procedure call inside the loop would most likely prevent the compiler to optimize awway the loop though.